# How to stop the user from entering the same value twice?

Tags: c

I am making a C program which aims to input numbers and store them in an array, but I have as a restriction that the same number cannot be entered twice.
Any idea of how to implement it?

Here is my code:

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
int n=0, num=0, i, j;
int N[n];
        printf("Write the amount of values that you will introduce\n");
        do {
           scanf("%d",&n);
           if(n<0)
              printf("Invalid number, try again\n");
        } while (n<0);
        printf("Remember to use numbers between 0 and 50\n");
        for(i=0; i<n; i++) {
            do {
                scanf("%d",&num); //If a repeated value is entered, show a message and request the number again       
                    if(num<0 || num>50){
                    printf("Invalid number, try again\n");
                }else{
                    N[i]=num;
                    printf("- - - - -\n");
                }
            } while (num<0 || num>50);
            getchar();
            getchar();
            return 0;
        
        }
    }
```

Comment: When the user enters a number you'll need to search the array of existing numbers to see if that value is already used and handle that case appropriately.

Comment: Well, you let the user input a value, and, if it was already in the array, output a message and loop back the input prompt. Remark: An array of length 0 (your N[n], with n == 0) is non-standard, and in any case doesn't let you assign values to any elements because there are none. The simple way is to define an array that is big enough to cover all most cases, and check the number of inputs against the maximum.

Comment: Rather than a O(N^2) search for every addition, it should be noted that your input range is heavily restricted to values in the range [0, 250].  Technically, you can maintain four 64-bit integers and use bitwise operations to keep a record of which value has been added.

Comment: It's not very good to have code like `num<0 || num>50`  written in multiple places if you can avoid it.  (See my answer.)

Comment: Indeed...  Magic numbers are not desirable.  Named constants are better.  That would also help with the part of your program that already digresses from the logic, where it asks the user to _"use numbers between 0 and 250"_ but then rejects everything larger than 50.

Comment: If you have a small-ish (like, smaller than a million) range of possible numbers the  user can enter you can also simply have an array of bool or int where you store a flag for each number that has been entered... stupid but simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once the user adds a value, push it to an array. Then the user inputs a value again, go through the array to check if they value already exists. If it exists, then the user has already input the value before. In that case don't let the user input the same value. If not, let them. SIMPLE :)

Answer (score 1):

When the user enters a new number, use a `for` loop to look at all numbers already in the array.  If you find that the number is already in the array, then make them enter another number.  So your inner loop would look something like this:

```c
  while (1) {
    scanf("%d",&num);

    // Validation #1: value
    if (num < 0 || num > 50) {
      printf("Numero no valido, ingrese de nuevo el valor\n");
      continue;
    }

    // Validation #2: uniqueness
    bool duplicate = false;
    for (int k = 0; k < i; k++) {
      if (N[k] == num) {
        printf("Number is a duplicate.\n");
        duplicate = true;
        break;
      }
    }
    if (duplicate) { continue; }

    N[i] = num;
    break;
  }
```

Note that we use `continue` to jump back to the top of the current loop, and `break` to jump out of it.  There is no easy way to `break` or `continue` the loop one level above the current one (unless you allow the use of `goto`), so that is why I have to use a boolean flag named `duplicate`.

By the way, you might need to include `stdbool.h` to use the `bool` type.

Answer (score 1):

Because your value range is very small, it's very easy to record the fact that a number is in your list by setting a single bit.

Indeed, you have 51 possible values in the range [0, 50] so you can represent these with a 64-bit integer.  Standard integer types are in `<stdint.h>`, where you'll find `uint64_t`.

```
uint64_t in_list = 0;
int numbers[51];
int count = 0;

for(int num; count <= 50 && 1 == scanf("%d", &num); )
{
    if (num >= 0 && num <= 50) {
        if (!(in_list & (1ULL << num))) {
            numbers[count++] = num;
            in_list |= (1ULL << num);
        } else {
            printf("Value %d is already added.\n", num);
        }
    }
}
```

There is still an unpleasant amount of hard-coded values here, but that can be improved, and even extended for higher ranges.  For simplicity, let's assume zero is always the minimum.  And since we'll need an array for the bits, we don't even have to use 64-bit values.  Simply characters are fine.

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX_NUM 250

int main()
{
    uint8_t in_list[(MAX_NUM / 8) + 1] = { };
    
    int numbers[MAX_NUM + 1];
    int count = 0;
    
    for(int num; count <= MAX_NUM && 1 == scanf("%d", &num); )
    {
        if (num >= 0 && num <= MAX_NUM) {
            int char_select = num / 8;
            int bit_mask = 1 << (num % 8);
            if (!(in_list[char_select] & bit_mask)) {
                numbers[count++] = num;
                in_list[char_select] |= bit_mask;
            } else {
                printf("Value %d is already added.\n", num);
            }
        } else {
            printf("Enter a value between 0 and %d.\n", MAX_NUM);
        }
    }
}
```